# Using trackbar to adjust color filter of an image

Tags: c#, image, filtering, trackbar

I m trying to do wat my title above says however i m there is no change on my pic when i scroll the trackbar. i noe there is sth missing in my code ... can anyone help me out with this ? greatly appreciate it.

```
private void SetTrackBarProp()
    {
        trackBar1.Maximum = 255;
        trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        trackBar1.TickFrequency = 1;
    }

    private Bitmap ApplyRGBFilter(Bitmap pic2)
    {
        ColorFiltering filter = new ColorFiltering();
        filter.Red = new IntRange(0, red);
        filter.Blue = new IntRange(0, blue);
        filter.Green = new IntRange(0, green);
        Bitmap processedImage = filter.Apply(pic2);
        return processedImage;
    }

    void picturebox2(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        pictureBox2.Image = ApplyRGBFilter(pic2);
    }


    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        red = trackBar1.Value;
    }
```

Above is just a snippet of my code on the filtering part, "pic2" is the image that i can browsed from my computer with the browse button i had in my application. pictureBox2 will be the place where my pic2 will appear.
THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE !

Comment: It is not clear whether you are having problems with the filtering part or the control part.

Comment: i m having problems with applying the filter to the image

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear that the header files for the `ColorFiltering` function. The only drawback of this Program is  note of Header files.